# How can I get a list of all namespaces within a specific Kubernetes cluster, using the Kubernetes API?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, cluster-computing

I need to get a list of all namespaces in a specifc Kubernetes cluster, using the Kubernetes API.  Because I need to loop through multiple clusters in my Python program, I need to specify the cluster every time I call the API.

One option is to use list_namespace(), as described in https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md

However, this API doesn't allow me to specify the cluster.  It picks up the cluster from the current-context in my .kube config file.  If I remove or rename the config file, the API call fails completely.

I also found an extensions API at https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ExtensionsV1beta1Api.md

Unfortunately, there is no API there to retrieve a list of namespaces.  Is there some other API that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/master/config/kube_config.py) of the *kube_config* module you can use different arguments with the method *load_kube_config* to select your cluster:

> ```
> def load_kube_config(config_file=None, context=None,
>                      client_configuration=None,
>                      persist_config=True):
>     """Loads authentication and cluster information from kube-config file
>     and stores them in kubernetes.client.configuration.
>     :param config_file: Name of the kube-config file.
>     :param context: set the active context. If is set to None, current_context
>         from config file will be used.
>     :param client_configuration: The kubernetes.client.Configuration to
>         set configs to.
>     :param persist_config: If True, config file will be updated when changed
>         (e.g GCP token refresh).
>     """
> ```

If I understood the code correctly, you can do somewhat like the following:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
for file in files:
    config.load_kube_config(config_file=file)
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    response = v1.list_namespace()
    print(response)
```

EDIT: [This](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/e057f273069de445a2d5a250ac5fe37d79671f3b/examples/example4.py) is an example that uses the context argument **with a single kubeconfig file** to iterate over multiple clusters. In the kubernetes docs there is an entry on [Merging kubeconfig files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files). Basically after having a config file with multiple contexts you can load the file with `config.load_kube_config(config_file=file)` and load contexts with `client.load_kube_config(context="context2')`

P.S. You don't need to use *config.load_kube_config()* if you want to use a config file in the default path (*'~/.kube/config'*) or if you set a path in the KUBECONFIG environment variable.

Comment: Victor, that's basically what I am doing now.  I prefer to handle this through the API instead of using files, but it is working fine for me.  Thanks.

Comment: One way to quickly changing context with kubectl is using the [KUBECONFIG](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable) environment variable. Unfortunately there is an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/issues/62) in the Kubernetes API where it doesn't accept more than one context in this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Would you check this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/multiple_clusters.py)
There you can navigate between multiple contexts and list all pods within all namespaces

Apparently you just need to replace

```
list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
```

with

```
list_namespace()
```

Comment: I have used list_namespace(), and it lists all namespaces with a cluster, but it requires a .kube config file to specify the cluster.  Since I need to get namespaces from multiple clusters, I am using Victor Val's solution of multiple config files.